How can I connect Supabase to a java project (I'm not using any Framwork)
I cannot connect to supabase when using jdbc
jdbc:postgresql://aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432/postgres?user=postgres.cjuvpugyzospthkjonkz&password=[YOUR-PASSWORD]

My code:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // Establish Connection
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432/postgres?user=postgres.cjuvpugyzospthkjonkz&password=[YOUR-PASSWORD]");
            System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver is not found. Include it in your library path.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection to PostgreSQL failed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} 

Someone please give me the solution to fix this code

What happens when you run the code? Please include the output in the question text, including the full stack trace, if any.

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://ep-yellow-bird-a1up0xr8.ap-southeast-1.aws.neon.tech/hello?user=hello_owner&password=R6Ga7dHerUEI&sslmode=require
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:708)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:253)
at Main.main(Main.java:12)

Please edit the question and put it there, formatted as a code block so it will be easy to read

ok, so I'm trying connect Supabase but I can't connect to Supabase. The system keep sending this error " No suitable driver found ". However, I can normally connect to my local PostgreSql. I don't know what is the probem, but I guess the issue may come from my dependencies.

Yes, it sounds like the JDBC driver isn’t on the classpath when you run it

then can you show me how to fix it ?

There’s not enough information in the question to help. The problem is not with the code, it’s with the way it is being run. Please edit the question and provide more details.
